# Date field as dynamic source for contextual filter

Tags: views, 8

I need a views block with a contextual date filter, based upon a date field of the currently viewed node.

What I've got so far:

1. I already have created my base view with base filters and sorting.
2. I've added a relation to the current node ("Get the actual content from a content revision")
3. I've added a contextual filter Content ID, using Content ID from URL as default value

But I don't want the current node in my views block, I need the next two nodes in my views block, and I don't know how to do this part of the contextual filter:

`views_node.field_date > contextual_node.field_date`

Concrete use case:

I'm displaying the full view of "event node A", and on that full view of node A, I want to embed a views block, showing the next two "event nodes B and C" after the date of event node A (for selecting and ordering nodes B and C I want something similar to this pseudo-query: `select * from view_nodes where view_nodes.field_mydate > context_node.field_mydate order by view_nodes.field_mydate limit 2`)

Answer (score 2):

Use **hook_views_query_alter** to alter query filter based on current node id or created date of node and put limit 2.

*Where clause will be Like:*

1. nid > current_nid
2. created date > current node created date (this may create issue if we have imported node in bulk)

**Also we can do it from contextual filter as well** just add contextual filter for current node id, greater than current node id.

Comment: If you need node field in filter then you just add that field in contextual filter and alter condition in hook_views_query_alter,

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work with tokens? It provides the created-date for the current page/node. Then create a view showing nodes sorted by date. Add a filter where date is >= the node date or <= the node date. For the pager, chose show 1 and offset 1, so that only the "prev" or "next" item displays.

To filter starting from a certain date you'd use the token value. https://www.drupal.org/project/token

Another approach is setting filter values programmatically.There are some examples here: [How to get contextual filter in hook_views_query_alter or hook_views_pre_execute?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139289/how-to-get-contextual-filter-in-hook-views-query-alter-or-hook-views-pre-execute)

Pseudo code:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$view = Views::getView('test_view');

if (is_object($view) && is_object($node)) {
  $view->setArguments($args);
  $view->setDisplay('block');

  // Filter is applied by reference (no need for setHandler()).
  $filter = $view->display_handler->getHandler('filter', 'created');
  $filter->value['value'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($node->created->value, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
  // Good to change options too.
  $filter->options['value'] = $filter->value;

  $view->preExecute();
  $view->execute();

  print $view->render();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be my use case. I'm displaying the full view of node A, and on that full view of node A, I want to embed a views block, showing the next two nodes B and C (for selecting and ordering nodes B and C I want something like `where nodes_b_and_c.field_mydate > node_a.field_mydate`)

Comment: I think I didn't describe my problem well enough (sorry, english isn't my mother tongue): 
I do know how to embed a view block in a node template. And I know that I can contextually filter with taxonomy terms, but the same option doesn't exist for "normal" non-taxonomy-reference fields. I don't know how to pull in the date field from the context node into the contextual filter.

Comment: I understand. I'd recommend trying the token module (or advanced token module - google search). It allows using typing variables into fields used in the view. For example, [node:created](https://www.drupal.org/node/390482).

Comment: Will update comment above. If tokens didn't work, you'd follow solution #2: Create a View and embed using block. Then set filters with your embed code or `mytheme_views_alter` in mytheme.theme php.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I want to filter pages than are older than current page.

Contextual filter cannot work as we don't have access to the operator : @see [Is there a specific reason that views contextual filters lack the ability to specify the operator?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/252884/63221)

So I have for my work around:

1x contextual filter:

- Use content Id from URL + content validator content (exclude from results)

1x normal views filter:

- filter by created date is less than current with dummy value "2020-10-20 00:00:00"

On the block layout -> block settings I use "Content: ID Node from ID".

Then in the theme layer to override "2020-10-20 00:00:00" with node created date:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContextAwarePluginInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block__views_block__VIEW_ID__DISPLAY_ID().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_block__views_block__alumni_hub_previous_lessons_block_1(&$variables, $hook) {
  if (!isset($variables['elements']['#plugin_id'])
    || !isset($variables['elements']['#configuration'])) {
    return;
  }
  $block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
  // Plugin ID format is: views_block:VIEW_ID-DISPLAY_ID.
  $plugin_block = $block_manager->createInstance($variables['elements']['#plugin_id'], $variables['elements']['#configuration']);
  // Inject runtime contexts.
  if ($plugin_block instanceof ContextAwarePluginInterface) {
    $contexts = \Drupal::service('context.repository')->getRuntimeContexts($plugin_block->getContextMapping());
    \Drupal::service('context.handler')->applyContextMapping($plugin_block, $contexts);
    // Get the node entity from the contextual value now.
    $contextual_values = $plugin_block->getContextValues();
    if (isset($contextual_values['nid'])
      && $contextual_values['nid']->hasField('created')
      && !$contextual_values['nid']->get('created')->isEmpty()) {

      $date_timestamp = $contextual_values['nid']->created->value;
      $plugin_view = $plugin_block->getViewExecutable();
      $filter = $plugin_view->display_handler->getHandler('filter', 'created');
      // Actually line that changes stuff.
      // Set filter to show nodes earlier than current ndoe.
      $filter->value['value'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date_timestamp, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
      // Good to change options too.
      $filter->options['value'] = $filter->value;
      // Override render array.
      $variables['content'] = $plugin_block->build();
    }
  }
}
```