# Is there a specific reason that views contextual filters lack the ability to specify the operator?

Tags: 8, views

When working with views filters, the admin can specify if the database query is equal to, contains, starts with, or greater than the value provided. Both the operator and value can be exposed to the user. Contextual filters lack this function, and must be equal to the value provided. Is there a specific reason that this was left out? I have edited the core StringArgument to give it the same operators as the StringFilter. Is there a reason (security, feature overlap) that I shouldn't submit this as a feature addition?

Comment: `I have edited the core StringArgument` Yikes, you violated the cardinal rule of Drupal, never hack core. You could achieve the same result with [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.4.x).

Comment: If you want to add a feature patch, you have to edit the core files.

Comment: However, if I did try to do this with a module, how would I completely override the existing `query()` function instead of altering it with the hook? It might be worthwhile doing this do demonstrate what the new function would look like and get some interest and adoption to push a core patch through.

Comment: Where is the `query()` that you speak of located?

Comment: It’s in the core src/views/argument/StringArgument.php file..I think that name is correct, not in front of my computer right now.

Comment: I've posted a question the drupal issue queue:  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3177845