# How to alter SQL queries in theme layer in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, database

In Drupal 7, we could use

> hook_query_alter()

in theme layer since `drupal_alter()` made modules and theme run the alter functions, but in Drupal 8, it seems this as been restricted to custom modules...

Is this true? or can themes partake too? another way?

I have a view, that i will change context argument depending on page it is rendered.

Comment: @see a workaround: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297515/63221