# How do I programmatically set contextual filters?

Tags: views, 8

I need to set a contextual filter programmatically and *almost* every view I have will have this filter. However, some wont and will have other contextual filters instead.

I have tried following the examples in [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139289/how-to-get-contextual-filter-in-hook-views-query-alter-or-hook-views-pre-execute) but this will just set the first argument to be my filter value regardless of what field is it for.

In `views_pre_build` I get the keyed arguments list under `$view->argument` and can do `->setArgument()` but this doesn't change the set of results.

Is there an easier way of setting a specific contextual filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contextual filters use query string params.  You could hard code these into the URL.  If using a Url object, you can pass a third argument ['query' => ['param1 => 'param1_value',...]].  Try setting a filter and seeing what the URL param name & value is after doing so.

In hook_views_pre_build(), you can also set the filter value directly:

```
$view->filter['filter_name']->value = 'filter_value';
```

It's helpful to have Xdebug so you can see the names of existing filters.  If you don't have xdebug, try finding the correct filter name in the ->filter property, then find the desired filter value, and put 2 and 2 together.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `$view` object, you can pass contextual filter params using the setArguments() method. Here is an example I'm using to pass four nids to the view to filter the results contextually:

```
$view->setArguments(['125+109+110+111']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_module_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'viewname' && $view->getDisplay()->display['id'] == 'machinenameOfDisplay') {
      dump( $view->args ); //you will get all the argument
      $view->args[1] = 'your value' //set specific argument
  }
}
```